# A word to describe "a curve and inaccurate road"?

Tags: word-request, image-identification

Is there a word to describe "a curve and inaccurate road"?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "an *inaccurate* road"?  "inaccurate" isn't a word I've ever heard applied to a road.

Comment: As a learner, I can suggest two adjectives which can be used to describe such roads.

1. twisting

2. winding

Comment: I mean It isn't a straight road.

Comment: @Cardinal Are there any difference between those 2 words?

Comment: I do not know. There must be some differences; otherwise we would have only one word rather than two words! :D

Comment: Ok :) I understood.

Comment: @ColleenV: I beg to differ about the possible duplicate: the other question features pictures of Alpine roads with lots of hairpin bends, whereas this a more typically English country road that just isn't quite sure where it's going.

Comment: @JavaLatte The same words that you state in your answer are in answers for the other question. I don't look at the way the question is stated so much as the answers when I'm choosing duplicates because the close reason says "Your question may already have an **answer** here". I can see why you don't think they're duplicates, but I think that they are similar enough that it would be useful to learners to have them tightly linked. It would be great if the answers did explain the difference between a long winding road and one with switchbacks and hairpin turns for either question though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is [the long and winding road](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Long_and_Winding_Road) that features in Paul McCartney's song of that name.

The word [winding](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/winding) is probably the most appropriate. Alternatives are:

[bendy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bendy) - especially of a road, having many bends

[twisty](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/twisty) - Not arranged or moving in a straight line; winding.

The term [meandering](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/meandering) is mainly used about rivers, but could also be used about roads that change direction frequently.

There are also quite a few appropriate descriptions in [The Rolling English Road](http://www.poetrybyheart.org.uk/poems/the-rolling-english-road/) by G K Chesterton.